# Replace letter $ for ;$ in csv/text file in powershell script

Tags: powershell

I have code in PowerShell and I need to replace letter `$` for `;$` or insert `;`

CSV file:

```
"11/23/2018 17:10:08"$"https://www.google.com"
"11/23/2018 17:10:20"$"https://www.yahoo.com"
```

And I need file:

```
11/23/2018 17:10:08;$https://www.google.com
11/23/2018 17:10:20;$https://www.yahoo.com
```

PS: Is it possible to find the titles to URLs?

```
(Get-Content C:\Users\user\Desktop\test\import.txt) | 
Foreach-Object {$_ -replace '"'} |
Foreach-Object {$_ -replace "$", ';$'} | 
Set-Content C:\Users\user\Desktop\test\export.txt
```

The wrong result is:

`11/23/2018 17:03:46$https://www.seznam.cz;$`

Answer (score 5):

You need to escape $ since it has a special meaning in a regular expression (end of text).

```bsh
(Get-Content C:\Users\user\Desktop\test\import.txt) | 
Foreach-Object {$_ -replace '"'}|
Foreach-Object {$_ -replace "\$", ';$'} | 
Set-Content C:\Users\user\Desktop\test\export.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

It's an one-liner:

```
$inputFile  = 'C:\test.txt'
$outputFile = 'C:\test1.txt'

[System.IO.File]::ReadAllLines($inputFile) | % { $_.Replace( '"$"', ';$' ).Trim('"') } | Out-File $outputFile
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use multiple `-replace` in one command as follows:

```
(Get-Content C:\Users\user\Desktop\test\import.txt) | 
Foreach-Object {$_ -replace '"' -replace '$', ';$'}|
Set-Content C:\Users\user\Desktop\test\export.txt
```

Comment: Output will still be buggy, `$` is a metacharacter in regex